# cakephp 2.1 json error 404 for jquery get

Tags: jquery, json, cakephp

Using cake 2.1, I'm trying to get a list of json records via ajax. Can't find what is missing:

On routes.php, added:

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

The action in my controller:

```
public function getdirs($id = null) {
    $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json', 'application/json');
    $dirArray = $this->Dir->find('all');
    debug($dirArray);
    $this->set('dirArray', $dirArray);
    $this->set('_serialize', 'dirArray');
}
```

From my view, (editing a parent record -101- and need to get its children), i'm using this jquery:

```
function updateTable() {
    var path = "/dirs/getdirs/101.json"; 
    $.post(path,null,function(data) {
    //$.get(path, function(data) {
        alert('backFromServer');
        alert(data);
    });        
}
```

The 'backfromserver' alert is not reached.
Also, i'm not sure how I could test where the error might be.

Once I get the json data, will fill up a div section on my view, this part i got covered, but need my data from server.

I'd really appreciate some help, been struggling with this for days now.

Thank you !!

**Update**
fixed to .json extension and removed auto-render; firebug response is:

```
{"code":"404","url":"\/dirs\/getdirs\/101.json","name":"Controller class Controller could not be found."}

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://dev.opm.asc/dirs/getdirs/101.json"
```

Double checked my action, it's called getdirs allright:

```
public function getdirs($id = null) {
    $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json', 'application/json');
    $dirArray = $this->Dir->find('all');
    debug($dirArray);
    $this->set('dirArray', $dirArray);
    $this->set('_serialize', 'dirArray');
}
```

What could be reason for the action not to be found?

As for the generic view, in this case i just want get a hold of the data array and fill up some div;

Please help.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 404 error was due to rights I've defined on top of my controller, such as:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    $AuthAddRoles = array(0, 1);
    if ($this->request->action === 'add') {
        if (in_array($this->Auth->user('role'), $AuthAddRoles)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I just had to authorize the ajax action in the same manner and it was resolved.

Thank you dubvfan87 for all the good pointers. Now the json response comes with  code at the beginning, solved here: [cakephp render-false action still echoes html template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062097/cakephp-render-false-action-still-echoes-html-template)

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = "/dirs/getdirs/101.js";
```

shouldn't this be

```
var path = "/dirs/getdirs/101.json";
```

Try installing firebug - http://getfirebug.com/ or pushing F12 if you're in chrome for chrome's developer tools. This will get you setup debugging http. Try the network tab. You can inspect the request and see exactly where your error is. This will let you see exactly what is being sent and what is being received.

Also, not sure if you posted partial code but if you do:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

you need to call render manually

```
$this->render('path/to/view');
```

I would recommend creating a generic view you can share between actions for outputting json.

Comment: Thank you dubvfan; fixed to .json extension and removed auto-render; Firebug response is:  "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://dev.opm.asc/dirs/getdirs/101.json". What could be reason for the action not to be found? . Double checked action name; see updated post.       Please help.

Comment: I think you want $dirArray = $this->Dir->find('all'); no 's', because models have singular names.

Comment: That's right. Fixed that but still getting "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://dev.opm.asc/dirs/getdirs/101.json"  :-( I'll keep on searching on thin 404 error. mmmh   (edited post).  Thanks a lot !.

Comment: Check your routes and make sure you mod_rewrite is working with the correct .htaccess files.

Comment: Thank you dubvfan87; found out the issue and put as another response. Thank you again !!